# How to perform readonly or disabled in ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Actually i am trying to set a field as readonly or disabled in ionic2 form as:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Category <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon></ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [disabled]="false" id="category_name" class="form-control" formControlName="category_name" (click)="category()" [(ngModel)]="category_name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I also used [readonly]="false".

I know it's an issue with  also there are issues on git :

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6408 ..

So any help how i could fix it out.

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5280. The disabled is fixed, but the readonly not yet

Comment: Ya thanks @Oswald i fixed this. Can you please help me out in one thing basically i am having a form in which if its not validated i am need to highlight required fields with a red line. Can you tell me how i can achieve the same.

Comment: If it is the same like in ionic1. you just have to use an additional class if valid/invalid like this:  ng-class="isValidPassword(content) ? 'valid icon ion-locked placeholder-icon' : 'icon ion-locked placeholder-icon'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have used this to solve in Ionic 2:

```
  In .ts file:
  ------------
  isReadonly() {
    return this.isReadonly;   //return true/false 
  }


  In .html file:
  --------------
  <ion-input type="text"  [readonly]="isReadonly()"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked fine.

```
<ion-input type="text" [readonly]="!userSessionStarted" value="" [(ngModel)]="userQuery" (change)="sendQueryToServer()"></ion-input>
```

The variable was toggled between true/false by ui-logic , not necessary that only functions can be used.